# Use rowspan on an empty cell of a previous row

Tags: css, html-table

I want to fuse a cell with the cell of the previous row in a shopping cart.
Here is what I want to do

[Table rowspan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUyNN.jpg)

No problem for the first and last columns, I just use rowspan on cell 1 and 4 then hide cell 5 and 8, but how can I do the same for cells 3 and 7 ? I know I could use Javascript and appendTo the content of the cell 7 into the cell 3 then use rowspan on cell 3, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do that only with CSS.

My code looks like that right now :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">Image</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan="2">Price</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the cell "Delete" to fill both rows, and I can't swap its content with the empty cell on the above TR.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this have to be done with table elements? Grid would be a good option for this.

Comment: I'd rather not change too much code just for that little issue. If I can't do it with table I'll just use javascript instead.